# UI doesnt refresh when view removed from Scroll view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have two scroll views, one scrolls horizontally and one scrolls vertically. I add views to one of the scroll views and display it. When user clicks back i remove the views from one of the scroll views and add them to the other scroll views as thumbnails.

Code is as follows:

```
for(UIView *views in verticalScrollView.subviews)
{
    [views removeFromSuperview];

}   

for(UIView *views in horizontalScrollView.subviews)
{
    [views removeFromSuperview];
}
```

However the scroll views get created but the views from the prev scroll view can still be seen in the background. How do i refresh/remove them from the scroll views completely. I dont hold any other reference to the views.

EDIT:

The methods described below are not working. I remove the subviews from the scroll views. However the images are still visible in the background.

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
for(UIView *subview in [verticalScrollView subviews]) 
{
    if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {//Or whatever kind of control you want to remove
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    } else {
    // Do nothing - if not a control subclass instance, you want to remove
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to check :

```
- (void)setNeedsDisplay
```

Comment: Nope it doesnt work. Anyways i have used the method for horizontal scroll view from this post http://blog.proculo.de/archives/180-Paging-enabled-UIScrollView-With-Previews.html. Can this be leading to some problems?